# Why Celery tasks don't work asynchronously?

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to run asynchronously basic `debug_task` from celery but it runs always synchronously.

I have created a new project with [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) template.

I made sure that redis is working and all env variables are valid.

I launch celery, and when it is ready to receive tasks, I launch the console (shell_plus) and invoke the task asynchronously.

```
In [1]: from project.taskapp.celery import debug_task                                                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: debug_task.delay()                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Request: <Context: {'id': '87b4d96e-9708-4ab2-873e-0118b30f7a6b', 'retries': 0, 'is_eager': True, 'logfile': None, 'loglevel': 0, 'hostname': 'hostname', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'headers': None, 'delivery_info': {'is_eager': True}, 'args': (), 'called_directly': False, 'kwargs': {}}>
Out[2]: <EagerResult: 87b4d96e-9708-4ab2-873e-0118b30f7a6b>
```

As you can see param `is_eager` == True -> so it worked sync.
Also I tried to call task as `debug_task.apply_async()`

Here are setting from cookiecutter template for celery:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps, AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


if not settings.configured:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')  


app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


class CeleryAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'project.taskapp'
    verbose_name = 'Celery Config'

    def ready(self):
        installed_apps = [app_config.name for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()]
        app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: installed_apps, force=True)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

Comment: Some setting CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER in one of the files?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Thank you. Forgot that in local settings might be also celery settings.. I tried to set  CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER= False in base settings but it was rewritten

Answer (score 0):

As many commenters have pointed out:  turn off eager processing when you configure celery:

```
app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.task_always_eager = False
```